# Smooth boundary of a domain with respect to smooth functions.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> Let $f\in C^{2}(U)$ where $U\subset \mathbb{R^n}$and $\partial U$ is $C^2$ If we let a level set of $a$ :
> $A=\left\{ x\in U\ :\ f(x)=a\right\} $ for a fixed $a$ in image of $f $,
> then $A$ is a curve.
>
> How can we make sure that $A$ is $C^2$-curve?

It looks obvious, but is difficult to make sure.

Comment: @Nameless note that $\partial A$ is a curve in $U$

Comment: @Nameless it could be but not generally.

Comment: @Nameless I editted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is that $A$ is not necessarily a curve. (Just imagine a constant function $f \equiv a$.) But even if $A$ is a curve for some $a$, then $A$ is not necessarily a $C^2$-curve. E.g., consider the function $f(x,y)=x^3-y^2$. Its contour plot is as follows:

[image]

Clearly, the level set $\{f=0\}$ is not smooth.